# $(...).getJSON is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to develop a simple API call that returns my comments in a JSON response but when I click on it I get the error

`$(...).getJSON is not a function`

My idea is, when I click on the button "Comment"(id=showarea) it immediately prints the comments from that answer and the textarea.

I'm "hardcoding" on the file just for testing.

I had this file (javascript/askme/comment.js)

```
function initCommentReloader() {
    $('#textarea').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $.getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", {answerid: answerid}, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
                console.log(comment);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

but when nothing happens that way, it doesn't even recognize the click,
then I changed to an hardcode way and the error happened. I checked my jquery include and everything seems properly included.

This is the file where I'm trying to load the comments. Can you find anything wrong?

I'm sorry if this is extreme newbie, but I've been stressing this way too much.

Kind regards

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>AskMe</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        } );
    </script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/fonts/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/styles/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/styles/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$BASE_URL}css/styles/clean-blog.min.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}javascript/vendor/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "{$BASE_URL}javascript/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{$BASE_URL}javascript/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.2/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>


<div class="post-button clearfix">
                <button class="btn icon-chat" title="Add a comment on this answer"
                        type="submit" id="showarea" name="showarea" value="Show Textarea">
                    Comment</button>
                <div id="textarea">
                    {include file="comment.tpl"}
                    {include file="comment_form.tpl"}
                </div>
            </div>

<script>
    answerid = {$answer['answerid']};
    console.log();
    $("#showarea").click(function() {
        $("#showarea").getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
{HTML::script('askme/comment.js')}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#textarea>a', function() {
  $.getJSON(
    "/controller/api/comments/comment.php", 
    {answerid: answerid},
    function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
        console.log(comment);
      });
    }
  );
});
```

**OR**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#textarea>a', function() {
  $.getJSON( "/controller/api/comments/comment.php", {
    answerid: answerid
  }).done(function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
      console.log(comment);
    });
  });
});
```

**OR**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#textarea>a', function() {
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/controller/api/comments/comment.php",
    data: {answerid: answerid},
    success: success
  }).done(function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
      console.log(comment);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

It may not be the particular issue here, but the same confusing error comes up if using the "slim" version of jQuery which excludes ajax, animations, etc.
If ".slim" appears in the line which includes jQuery, try taking that out.

Also, check the browser console to be sure jQuery is loading properly and not getting a 404 or similar error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe change

```
$("#showarea").getJSON
```

to

```
$.getJSON
```

Comment: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` , if I do that, I get this

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't understand what the question is. I'm pretty sure `$("#showarea").getJSON(...)` is causing the error in your subject line

Comment: @LuísCosta Are you sure you have $.getJSON and not $("#").getJSON?

Comment: `function initCommentReloader() {
    $('#textarea').on('click', 'a', function() {
        $.getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", {answerid: answerid}, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, comment) {
                console.log(comment);
            });
        });
    });
}` 

I have this. I'm pretty sure :)

Comment: Dude, we're talking about `$("#showarea").click(function() {
        $("#showarea").getJSON("/controller/api/comments/comment.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });` do you have here `$.getJSON()`??

Comment: I do! I just pasted it.

Answer (score 1):

May be due to jQuery version, you need to change

```
$.getJSON
```

to

```
jQuery.getJSON
```

Another option is droping **$.getJSON** and using **$.ajax** as (according to jQuery documentation) **$.getJSON** is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success
});
```